# ARKit How to draw measurement scale

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I wonder how this to be done . Please do not close this question I need suggestion or any hint to implement it.

Source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uHyHRKmxZk

[image]

I have created A node  which is  `SCNCylinder` and drawn from target to the centre of the screen  from `updateAtTime` method

Firstly I thought it was drawn with TextNode. SO I tried following

Inside that class I have method help to draw a node at each Unit I pass to `UnitLength`

```
func drawOtherBaseUnit(height:Float,intoThe unitType:UnitLength,toTheNode zAxisNode:SCNNode) {

    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
    let distanceInTarget = Converter.convert(value: Double(height), to: unitType).output + 1
    print("DISTANCE",distanceInTarget)
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")

    var text = ""
    switch unitType {
        case .inches:
            text = "INCH"
    case .centimeters:
            text = "CM"

    default:
        return
    }

    if !distanceInTarget.isNaN {
        var  distance = Int(distanceInTarget)
        var i = 0
        while  distance > 0 {
            print("distance ",distance)
            let node = UnitNode(withPosition: SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0), radius: CGFloat(Converter.convert(value: 0.1, from: unitType, to: UnitLength.meters).output),text:"\(text) \(i)",forType:unitType)
            let valueIncreaseOnAsPerTarget = Int(distanceInTarget) -  distance
            let valueToIncreaseMeter = Converter.convert(value: Double(valueIncreaseOnAsPerTarget), from: unitType, to: UnitLength.meters).output
            node.position.y = -Float(valueToIncreaseMeter) 
            node.position.x = 0 
            zAxisNode.addChildNode(node)
            distance -=  1
            i  += 1
        }
    }
}
```

The `UnitNode` class is draw SCNText and some other nodes.

This is working fine. I can see node each provided unit.

[image]

But it if I use `drawOtherBaseUnit` for Inch as well as CM UI is Lagging it is not smooth.

Is it correct way to implement desired output ?

Comment: If you are rendering lots of SCNText instances this will definitely increase the CPU significantly. One way to improve performance is to set the flatness to 1 although the text won’t look smooth. Another thing you can do is create one instance of your blue cylinder and then copy it using node.clone()

Comment: @JoshRobbins Thanks for your replay i will definitely try this. Do you have idea how target output is done ? Like is it  image or sameThing I Did ?

Comment: I would hazard a guess it uses images although without spending sometime making an example I couldn’t say for sure. I am certain however that using SCNText is probably not the right approach. The reason being that when I was working on an example of numbering the vertices of an ARPlaneGeometry using SCNText, I had for example 14 instances of SCNText and the CPU was overloaded :)

Comment: @JoshRobbins Thank you :) I will search for other ways